# What can I use instead of mysql_fetch_array?

Tags: php

In my php code I take data from the database and I put to a specific values ​​of the Array:

```
$from_db=mysql_query(" SELECT * FROM ... ");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($from_db)) {
$number_id[]=$row['number_id'];
...
}
```

And now I would like add this line (for other purposes) before comand "while":

```
$from_db = mysql_fetch_array($from_db);
```

How can I change this line: `while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($from_db)) {` to process an array instead of a raw data from database?

Comment: your question is way unclear. in both cases you have arrays both contains raw data from database. Can you tell what you actually want, and why? Without using some terms you don't quite understand. Thanks.

Comment: I tried put `$from_db` to cache, but I got an error, so I needed convert mysql_query to an Array, put in into cache and after that process.

Comment: WHAT you want to put into cache? what for? Do you really need any cache? May be you need to learn very basic syntax first?

Comment: I needed put result from `mysql_query(" SELECT * FROM ... ")` into cache. But mysql_query result need to be converted to an Array before will be saved on a disk for future use.

Comment: why do you want this cache at all? do you have your query slow or what? most queries require no caching, mysql can cache query results better than you can do. Do you have any certain reason to cache query results?

Comment: Thanks for information. Also I wanted compare disk cache with CacheAPCDriver (put some results into memory). So maybe I should think to cache result of already formated view for user, not just raw data from mysl_query. Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you use [PDO class](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead. mysql_* functions are not recommended anymore and will be deprecated in the (far) future.

An example is something like:

```
//Connect to database and whatnot
//...
$PDOquery=$PDO->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=?;');
$PDOquery->execute(array(1));
$resultArray=$PDOquery->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); //Results stored as associative array in ths array.
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this is unfortunately necessary:

```
$from_db=mysql_query(" SELECT * FROM ... ");

$from_db = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($from_db)) {
  $from_db[] = $row;
}

foreach($from_db as $row) {
  $number_id[]=$row['number_id'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would better use [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

For example, [PDOStatement::fetchAll](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php):

```
<?php
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT name, colour FROM fruit");
$sth->execute();

/* Fetch all of the remaining rows in the result set */
print("Fetch all of the remaining rows in the result set:\n");
$result = $sth->fetchAll();
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
mysql_fetch_assoc()
mysql_fetch_object()
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php